# Can batch files execute (local) Java code from a local machine to a remote machine

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

**Background:** I am trying to run some Java code on a few target machines (to check registry values using JNA) and I don't want to have to install Java on every machine I need to check.  I thought that a possible solution was having the server running the Java app use a batch file that lives on the local server.  This batch file would simply call a Java program and get the data I needed from the remote machines.

**Question:**  I have a local batch file that I am executing using Java.  This batch file will remote execute on target machines.  The batch file calls/runs a Java program.  Is it possible for that Java program to live on the main server or does it need to live on the target machines as well?

Answer (score 0):

if understood right, you could just say to the batch file to print a report of registry info that you are searching, then use java to directly reach that report, and then you could "analyze" that code in your "server"

with this you don't need to have java installed on local machine, and you don't need to launch "application" but simply: a script.

Comment: Not quiet the right idea.  Make the "script" simple, just calling a Hello World java program on target machines.  Ultimately where does that "HelloWorld" jar or whatever need to live?

Comment: well, if you don't want to have java, the "script" must be inside the other machine, while the server (you or whatever) with java, simply call the script on localmachine

another idea, you could do it like scheduled on local and with java just "retriv" info =)